# How to add vertical lines to a distribution plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

Using the examples from [seaborn.pydata.org](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) and the [Python DataScience Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.14-visualization-with-seaborn.html), I'm able to produce a combined distribution plot with the following snippet:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some settings
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

# Create some data
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [[5, 2], [2, 2]], size=2000)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y'])

# Combined distributionplot
sns.distplot(data['x'])
sns.distplot(data['y'])
```

**Plot:**
[image]

How can I combine this setup with vertical lines so that I can illustrate thresholds like this:

[image]

I know I can do it with matplotlib like here [Dynamic histogram subplots with line to mark target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112092/dynamic-histogram-subplots-with-line-to-mark-target/52114420#52114420), but I really like the simplicity of seaborn plots and would like to know if it's possible to do it more elegantly (and yes, I know that seaborn builds on top of matplotlib).

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24988448/7758804)  because `plt.axvline` is [already covered (Jul 28, 2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988486/7758804). The implementation here is not different because it's a distribution, or seaborn (distplot has been removed). Additionally, there's a better description, and more options in the duplicate.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just use

```
plt.axvline(2.8, 0,0.17)
```

And the same for the other line

Here instead of 0.17 you can put the maxima of your distribution using some variable such as `maxx = max(data)` or something similar. 2.8 is the position on the x-axis.  Oh remember that the y-value has to be in between 0 and 1 where 1 is the top of the plot. You can rescale your values accordingly. Another obvious option is simply

```
plt.plot([2.8, 2.8], [0, max(data)])
```