# How to draw a vertical line at the mode of the seaborn distplot

Tags: python, seaborn, density-plot

I just learned how to draw a density plot with the `seaborn` Python module:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import (plot, savefig, xlim, figure,
                              ylim, legend, boxplot, setp,
                              axes, xlabel, ylabel, xticks,
                              axvline)
import seaborn as sns

layer1_G1_G2 = [-0.05567627772688866,
 -0.06829605251550674,
 -0.0721447765827179,
 -0.05942181497812271,
 -0.061410266906023026,
 -0.062010858207941055,
 -0.05238522216677666,
 -0.057129692286252975,
 -0.06323938071727753,
 -0.07018601894378662,
 -0.05972284823656082,
 -0.06124034896492958,
 -0.06971242278814316,
 -0.06730005890130997]

def make_density(layer_list,color, layer_num):

    layer_list_tensor = torch.tensor(layer_list)
    
    # Plot formatting
    plt.title('Density Plot of Median Stn. MC-Losses at Layer ' + layer_num)
    plt.xlabel('MC-Loss')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    plt.xlim(-0.2,0.05)
    plt.ylim(0, 85)
    min_ylim, max_ylim = plt.ylim()
    
    # Draw the density plot
    sns.distplot(layer_list, hist = False, kde = True,
                 kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color=color)

# plot the density plot
# the resulting density plot is shown below
>>> make_density(layer1_G1_G2, 'green','1')
```

[image: Image generated from the code above:]

How can I draw a vertical line at the **mode of this density curve** on this `distplot`?

Thank you,

Comment: For calculating the mode of the list, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797819/finding-the-mode-of-a-list

Comment: For the vertical line, this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334938/seaborn-how-to-add-vertical-lines-to-a-distribution-plot-sns-distplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the x and y values of the generated curve and find the mode as the highest y-value.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

layer1_G1_G2 = [-0.05567627772688866, -0.06829605251550674, -0.0721447765827179, -0.05942181497812271, -0.061410266906023026, -0.062010858207941055, -0.05238522216677666, -0.057129692286252975, -0.06323938071727753, -0.07018601894378662, -0.05972284823656082, -0.06124034896492958, -0.06971242278814316, -0.06730005890130997]

def make_density(layer_list, color, layer_num):
    # Draw the density plot
    ax = sns.distplot(layer_list, hist=False, kde=True, kde_kws={'linewidth': 2}, color=color)
    x = ax.lines[0].get_xdata()
    y = ax.lines[0].get_ydata()
    mode_idx = y.argmax()
    ax.vlines(x[mode_idx], 0, y[mode_idx], color='crimson', ls=':')

    # Plot formatting
    ax.set_title('Density Plot of Median Stn. MC-Losses at Layer ' + layer_num)
    ax.set_xlabel('MC-Loss')
    ax.set_ylabel('Density')
    ax.autoscale(axis='x', tight=True)
    ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)

make_density(layer1_G1_G2, 'green', '1')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```py
def make_density(layer_list,color, layer_num):

    
    # Plot formatting
    plt.title('Density Plot of Median Stn. MC-Losses at Layer ' + layer_num)
    plt.xlabel('MC-Loss')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    plt.xlim(-0.2,0.05)
    plt.ylim(0, 85)
    min_ylim, max_ylim = plt.ylim()
    
    
    
    # Draw the density plot
    sns.distplot(layer_list, hist = False, kde = True,
                 kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color=color)
    
    dens_list = sns.distplot(layer1_G1_G2, hist = False, kde = True,
             kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color='green').get_lines()[0].get_data()[1].tolist()
                    
    max_dens_index = dens_list.index(max(dens_list))
    
    mode = sns.distplot(layer1_G1_G2, hist = False, kde = True,
             kde_kws = {'linewidth': 2}, color='green').get_lines()[0].get_data()[0].tolist()[max_dens_index]
  
    plt.axvline(mode, color='orange', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5)

    plt.text(mode * 0.87, 80, 'mode: {:.2f}'.format(mode))

>>> make_density(layer1_G1_G2, 'green','1')
```

[image]

Comment: Note that by calling `sns.distplot` 3 times, the same plot is drawn 3 times one over the other. This can be avoided by storing the returned `ax` into a variable.